# Java file cannot access methods even though class file is in same directory

Tags: java

I was given only a .class file for homework and need to write a program that accesses its methods. Well, I have the .class file in the same directory, but I cannot access its methods, so my program won't compile! I've tried on JGrasp and Eclipse. Both 'cannot find symbol' (the method name).

I am absolutely positive that I am using the right method names. Why isn't it working??

This is my code in Hw.java

```
public class Hw {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] a2 = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        int[] a3 = {1};
        int[] a4 = {2, 5, 3, 1, 4};
        int[] a5 = {1, 2, 1};

        System.out.println(sortA(a1));        
        System.out.println(sortA(a2));
        System.out.println(sortA(a3));
        System.out.println(sortA(a4));
        System.out.println(sortA(a5));        
  }
}
```

And the error I'm getting in JGrasp:

Hw.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(sortA(a1));
                               ^
  symbol:   method sortA(int[])
  location: class Hw

Comment: We cannot help without seeing the code.

Comment: pls post your sample code and the error you are getting.

Comment: is the method in some package?

Comment: Maybe the class in the .class file is not declared in a default package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sortA` is a static method of the class you are given, you have to qualify it with the class name:

```
System.out.println(GivenClass.sortA(a1));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create that class's instance and call the sort method.

```
    System.out.println(new ThatClass().sortA(a1));
```

If sortA(a1) is a static method you should call it on the class Name.

```
    System.out.println(ThatClassName.sortA(a1));
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you access method with out object from another class... If you are trying to all sort method then your your .class reference to call...

Answer (score 0):

You need to first import the particular class.. open the .class file a the top you will notice there is some package name written.. so take the note of it.. now place your class file in your eclipse.. and import that package in your Hw.java.. make sure you do this way.. say package name is p1 then write this way `import p1.*` to make sure you have all the classes present in it..
Now eclipse and other IDE have intellisense so you can take advantage of it.. I mean make an object of that class and using that object press period (dot  . ) to get to know the methods the class offer with there signature.. and use it..
One thing I have noticed that you have not created object to access sort method. You need to do that first.. and if the methods are static.. then do static import so you do not have to specify the class name.. something like this `import static p1.*`

Hope this helps!!